# A phrase whose meaning I do not fully understand because I can not read three words

Tags: phrase-meaning

I do not get the meaning of a phrase because I can not read three words. Below you can find a transcription of the text, and the handwritten original with the above mentioned words underlined.

> But I had a generous applause and Prof. Woodward and Prof. Rotch said
> some rather nice things. Prof. Zahm just wrote me: “Be sure to have it
> (the paper) well published; then continue to give us other papers. We
> need another Chanute to continue the critical history of aëronautics
> and you have now the ??? which I hope you will ??? with equal ???.

[image: February 2, 1905, Letter of Carl Dienstbach to the wright brothers]
[February 2, 1905, Letter of Carl Dienstbach to the wright brothers](https://www.loc.gov/resource/mwright.03082/?sp=2)

( As an explanation: The excerpt above is from a letter of Carl Dienstbach (a german journalist living in New York) to the Wright brothers. Dienstbach told the Wrights that he had participated at a conference where he "gave a historical and critical view of all the important steps toward the final practical accomplishment of mechanical flight starting with Lilienthal and ending with" the Wright brothers. His speech was appreciated by a few professors in the audience, and one of them, Prof. Zahm, wrote him the text I do not fully understand. (Chanute was an early aviation historian, amongst other things.) )

Answer (score 1):

The first two words are "mantle" and "wear".  A mantle is a type of cape, but here it is used metaphorically

> "take/wear the mantle (of)...":  to accept or have an important duty or job

The last word is completely illegible to me, but would continue the metaphor.  "... which you wear with equal  *?style* or *?flair*" or some similar word  (those don't match the writing, but the word would have some similar meaning)

Comment: Could the last word be "renown"? "you have now the mantle which I hope you will wear with equal renown".